# Taskset not working properly in OpenVZ container

Tags: debian, openvz, multi-core, containers

In a Debian OpenVZ container, I'm trying to use taskset to pin a process to a core, but it doesn't work:

```
root@foo:/# taskset -c -p 0 1754
pid 1754's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 1754's new affinity list: 0-7
```

The exact same thing works on the host.

Comment: I was able to do it from the host. I'm still not sure why it doesn't work from the container.

Answer (score 1):

As I recommended you in twitter there are few solutions:
`vzctl set XXXX --cpumask 0,1 --save`

And after this operations taskset should work. If it not working yet, please create ticket to bugzilla.openvz.org because it seems as bug.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It still doesn't work. I'm going to report it as a bug.